# How to convert multi column expressions from Pandas to Polars

Tags: python, pandas, python-polars

I just found out about the Polars lib and I wanted to convert some old functions to get familiar.

However, I stumbled upon an issue with my code. The "Mean_Angle" column is not calculated, and I have no idea if the last part even works as intended, it aborts during the groupby operation as the column is missing.

This is the code I want to convert:

```py
def calc_mean_and_error(df: pd.DataFrame, columns=None, groupby="Magn_Pos") -> pd.DataFrame:
    data = df.copy()
    if columns is None:
        columns = ['Left_Angle', 'Right_Angle', 'Magn_Pos', 'Magn_Field']

    if 'Left_Angle' in columns and 'Right_Angle' in columns:
        data['Mean_Angle'] = (data['Left_Angle'] + data['Right_Angle']) / 2
        columns.append('Mean_Angle')
    grouped_df = data[columns].groupby(groupby,sort=False)

    num_points_per_group = grouped_df.size().values
    mean_df = grouped_df.mean()

    # standard deviation
    mean_df[['Left_Angle_SDEV','Right_Angle_SDEV','Mean_Angle_SDEV']] = grouped_df[['Left_Angle','Right_Angle','Mean_Angle']].std()

    # standard error, 1 sigma confidence interval
    mean_df[['Left_Angle_SEM_68','Right_Angle_SEM_68','Mean_Angle_SEM_68']] = grouped_df[['Left_Angle','Right_Angle','Mean_Angle']].sem()

    # standard error, 2 sigma confidence interval - t distribution
    t_fac_95_conf_int = stats.t.ppf(0.95, num_points_per_group) # factor according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution
    mean_df[['Left_Angle_SEM_95','Right_Angle_SEM_95','Mean_Angle_SEM_95']] = mean_df[['Left_Angle_SEM_68','Right_Angle_SEM_68','Mean_Angle_SEM_68']].multiply(t_fac_95_conf_int, axis=0)

    # standard error, 3 sigma confidence interval - t distribution
    t_fac_99_conf_int = stats.t.ppf(0.997, num_points_per_group)
    mean_df[['Left_Angle_SEM_99','Right_Angle_SEM_99','Mean_Angle_SEM_99']] = mean_df[['Left_Angle_SEM_68','Right_Angle_SEM_68','Mean_Angle_SEM_68']].multiply(t_fac_99_conf_int, axis=0)

    mean_df = mean_df.reset_index()

    return mean_df
```

This is what I have so far:

```py
def calc_mean_and_error(df: pl.DataFrame, columns=None, groupby="Magn_Pos") -> pl.DataFrame:
    data = df
    if columns is None:
        columns = ['Left_Angle', 'Right_Angle', 'Magn_Pos', 'Magn_Field']

    if 'Left_Angle' in columns and 'Right_Angle' in columns:
# this doesn't work?
        data.with_column(
            pl.struct(['Left_Angle', 'Right_Angle']).apply(lambda x: (x['Left_Angle'] + x['Right_Angle']) / 2).alias("Mean_Angle")
        )
        columns.append('Mean_Angle')
    grouped_df = data.select(columns).groupy(groupby)

    num_points_per_group = grouped_df.count()['count'].take(0)
    mean_df = grouped_df.mean()

    t_fac_95_conf_int = stats.t.ppf(0.95, num_points_per_group) # factor according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution
    t_fac_99_conf_int = stats.t.ppf(0.997, num_points_per_group)
    # standard deviation
    mean_df = data.select(columns).groupby(groupby).agg(
        [
            pl.col('*').mean(),
            pl.col('*').std().suffix('_SDEV'),
            pl.col('*').std().apply(lambda x: x / np.sqrt(num_points_per_group)).suffix('_SEM_68'), # standard error
            pl.col('*').std().apply(lambda x: x*t_fac_95_conf_int / np.sqrt(num_points_per_group)).suffix('_SEM_95'),
            pl.col('*').std().apply(lambda x: x*t_fac_99_conf_int / np.sqrt(num_points_per_group)).suffix('_SEM_99'),
        ]
    )

    return mean_df
```

Example:

```py
data_raw = """Time\tRepetition\tLeft_Angle\tRight_Angle\tMagn_Pos\tMagn_Field
0.0\t0\t111.62539060014953\t111.65929559305457\t20.0\t0.05012
289.75\t1\t113.43406129503042\t113.29101205027376\t20.0\t0.05012
343.420999999973\t2\t113.21669960326668\t113.30918399000467\t20.0\t0.05012
397.68700000003446\t0\t114.50650196149256\t114.78488582815113\t10.0\t0.1317
456.10900000005495\t1\t114.7078936381882\t114.70239460290726\t10.0\t0.1317
507.8279999999795\t2\t115.71894177915732\t115.70104461571628\t10.0\t0.1317
565.3429999999935\t0\t121.71521327349599\t121.55379420624988\t5.0\t0.2276
612.045999999973\t1\t122.53171995914443\t122.4555143281342\t5.0\t0.2276
668.3120000000345\t2\t121.65748098845367\t121.60313424823333\t5.0\t0.2276
714.484000000055\t0\t130.88884567117995\t130.82365731381574\t2.5\t0.3011
774.9679999999935\t1\t132.72366563179372\t132.59019277520363\t2.5\t0.3011
817.765000000014\t2\t133.5549497954158\t133.4637401535662\t2.5\t0.3011
891.7029999999795\t0\t139.9155468732065\t139.78384156146674\t0.0\t0.3907
940.655999999959\t1\t143.34707217674438\t143.2278696177915\t0.0\t0.3907
984.125\t2\t144.30042471080577\t144.16800277145435\t0.0\t0.3907""".encode("utf8")

data = pl.read_csv(data_raw, sep='\t', encoding="utf8")
eval = calc_mean_and_error(data, columns=['Left_Angle', 'Right_Angle', 'Magn_Pos', 'Magn_Field'])
print(eval)
```

I'm not really sure about the last part though! I am not entirely familiar with the syntax of the expressions. And I am not sure how to prevent calling groupby twice.  Can someone lead me in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: Are there supposed to be tabs in `data_raw`? It's just spaces currently so everything is merged into a single column.

Comment: Oh? Yeah, those are supposed to be tabs. Dont know why they didnt copy

Comment: Maybe you could use `\t` instead? As there are 6 column names but 8 "values" on each row - it's not clear what is what.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I replaced the tabs with \t. Also I forgot to remove some columns from the data.

Comment: Not a problem - I can now run your function locally on the data to see what's happening - thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.with_column()` returns a new dataframe - it does not modify in-place.

You would assign the result:

```
data = data.with_column(...)
```

You don't need to use [`.apply()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.apply.html#polars.Expr.apply) here - you can use expressions:

```
data = data.with_column(
   ((pl.col("Left_Angle") + pl.col("Right_Angle")) / 2)
   .alias("Mean_Angle")
)
```

Regarding calling `.groupby()` twice - you're already using `grouped_df` - you could re-use it:

```
mean_df = grouped_df.agg(...)
```

However - it may make more sense to add the values you're using as columns and call groupby twice.

That way you can remove all the further calls to `.apply()` and use expressions instead:

```
# all columns excluding the "temporary" ones we will add
columns = pl.exclude(["t_fac_95_conf_int", "t_fact_99_conf_int", "sqrt"])

mean_df = data.with_columns([
   pl.lit(t_fac_95_conf_int).alias("t_fac_95_conf_int"),
   pl.lit(t_fac_99_conf_int).alias("t_fac_99_conf_int"),
   pl.lit(np.sqrt(num_points_per_group)).alias("sqrt")
]).groupby(groupby).agg([
   columns.mean(),
   columns.std().suffix("_SDEV"),
   (columns.std() / pl.col("sqrt")).first().suffix("_SEM_68"),
   (columns.std() * pl.col("t_fac_95_conf_int") / pl.col("sqrt")).first().suffix("_SEM_95"),
   (columns.std() * pl.col("t_fac_99_conf_int") / pl.col("sqrt")).first().suffix("_SEM_99"),
])
```

---

#### Further possible changes:

- Instead of the first groupby - you can use [`pl.count().over()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/dsl/window_functions.html)
- You can use [`.map()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.map.html#polars.Expr.map) to run the count column through `stats.t.ppf()` - [`.flatten()` is used to unwrap the list]
- As you now have a count column - `Expr.sqrt()` can be used instead of `np.sqrt()`

This should be equivalent:

```
columns = pl.exclude(["count", "sqrt", "t_fac_95_conf_int", "t_fac_99_conf_int"])
mean_df = (
   data
   .with_columns(pl.count().over(groupby))
   .with_columns([
      pl.col("count").map(lambda col: stats.t.ppf(0.95,  col)).flatten().alias("t_fac_95_conf_int"),
      pl.col("count").map(lambda col: stats.t.ppf(0.997, col)).flatten().alias("t_fac_99_conf_int"),
      pl.col("count").sqrt().alias("sqrt"),
   ])
   .groupby(groupby)
   .agg([
      columns.mean(),
      columns.std().suffix("_SDEV"),
      (columns.std() / pl.col("sqrt")).first().suffix("_SEM_68"),
      (columns.std() * pl.col("t_fac_95_conf_int") / pl.col("sqrt")).first().suffix("_SEM_95"),
      (columns.std() * pl.col("t_fac_99_conf_int") / pl.col("sqrt")).first().suffix("_SEM_99"),
   ])
)
```

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful. I must've missed that pandas part. Do I need to add t_fac_95_conf_int to that dataframe so I can use it in the expressions?

Comment: How do I prevent the agg for certain columns? It currently includes also the ones we add with `with_columns`. Also the std() falsly returns 0 for all?

Comment: Oops - didn't account for that. You can use [`.exclude()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.exclude.html#polars-exclude) - instead of repeating it each time - you can create a variable e.g. `columns = pl.exclude(["t_fac_95_conf_int", "t_fact_99_conf_int", "sqrt"])` then use  `columns.mean()`, `columns.std()`, etc.

Comment: With my dataset fixed, your solution does not produce 0 anymore, but the SEM columns are now lists of 3 values?

Comment: Is each value in the list the same? If so - you can add `.first()` before `.suffix()` e.g. `(...).first().suffix("_SEM_68")`

Comment: @Raphael I've added a further example showing how you could use `pl.count().over()` and `.map()` to implement the count/stats parts of your code inside the expressions which may be of interest.

Comment: Can you suggest some resource to learn more about Polars? Like a tutorial or something? The documentation explains the basics but not how the different concepts can work together in a complex example like this.

Comment: The 2 tutorials I have seen are https://calmcode.io/polars/introduction.html and https://kevinheavey.github.io/modern-polars/ - I'm not sure if they cover such complex examples - I've mostly learned from reading through previous questions here and on the github issues page.